# Getting the Background of a UIElement or sender

Tags: c#, wpf, background, dependency-properties, uielement

I'm trying to find a generic way to set the Background property on a UIElement.

I'm not having much luck...

Here's what I have so far (trying to use reflection to get the BackgroundProperty).

```
  Action<UIElement> setTheBrushMethod = (UIElement x) =>
  {
    var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    var whatever = x.GetType().GetField("BackgroundProperty");
    var val = whatever.GetValue(null);
    ((UIElement)x).SetValue(val as DependencyProperty, brush);
    brush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, new ColorAnimation(Colors.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
  };
  setTheBrushMethod(sender as UIElement);
```

The thing is...it works for something like a TextBlock, but does not work for something like a StackPanel or a Button.

"whatever" ends up being null for StackPanel or Button.

I also feel like there should be an easy way to generically set the Background.  Am I missing obvious?

Background only appears to be available on System.Windows.Controls.Control but I can't cast to that.

Comment: hmm.... have you considered using Styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reflection call is actually wrong: you are looking for the `Background` **PROPERTY**, not the `BackgroundProperty` **DEPENDENCYPROPERTY**

Here is what should be your `var whatever` :

```
var whatever = x.GetType().GetProperty("Background").GetValue(x);
x.GetType().GetProperty("Background").SetValue(x, brush);
```

And this will work fine

**SIDE NOTES:**

I strongly advice you to get rid of useless `var` and write the actual type you are waiting for (in this case, a `Brush`), that will make your code much easier to read

Also, why can't you just work on a `Control` and not an `UIElement` ? Seems pretty rare to me

Cheers!

Comment: Cheers!  This worked.

Replies to your notes:

1.  var is a bad habit I picked up from ReSharper.  Agreed.
2.  I need UIElement because this is actually part of the metadata changed event in an attachedProperty.  I have a RoutedEvent attachedProperty which will trigger a pulsing of a given UIElement.

Tough to explain over the internet.

Your help is very appreciated.